# Manipulating partials in solution of equation

Tags: partial-derivative

I'm given the following equation:

$$
\frac{\partial \dot u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial w}{\partial x}\frac{\partial \dot w}{\partial x} = 0
$$

where $u=u(x,t)$, $w=w(x,t)$ and $\dot{()} = \frac{\partial ()}{\partial t}$.  My goal is to solve for $\frac{\partial \dot u}{\partial \dot w}$.  One approach is to first solve for $\dot u$ as follows

$$
\dot u(x,t) = \int_0^x \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial \xi^2} \dot w{\rm d}\xi - \left[ \frac{\partial w(\xi, t)}{\partial \xi} \dot w \right]_0^{x}+\dot u(0,t)
$$

where integration-by-parts has been used.  Now take the partial of both sides with respect to $\dot w$ to get

$$
\frac{\partial \dot u}{\partial \dot w} = \int_0^x \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial \xi^2} {\rm d}{\xi} - \frac{\partial w}{\partial x}
$$

Alternatively, I don't know why I can't simply multiply the first equation by $\left( \frac{\partial \dot w}{\partial x}\right)^{-1}$ to get

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial \dot w}\frac{\partial \dot u}{\partial x} &= - \frac{\partial w}{\partial x}\frac{\partial \dot w}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial \dot w} \\
\frac{\partial \dot u}{\partial \dot w} &= - \frac{\partial w}{\partial x}
\end{align}

I'm assuming the first approach is correct and the second is incorrect, but I don't know why there is an error in the second.  Can someone explain it to me?